# Uses of Tables x Withe Space in Pages

Tags: tables

I'm writing a document and I have a problem with creating  tables. 
When I put a table in a page and haven't space sufficient the table go to the next page and the original page stay with a big white space...

How can I write a latex code that one part of table stay in the first page and the remainder of table go to the next page. I can't allow that a big white space stay on the page.

The code for my tables:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[verbose]{placeins}
\begin{document}
%%%% TABELA MEDIDAS DE TENSAO
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Medidas de Tensão}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.1cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{2.4cm}|}
\hline
 \textbf{Fonte de Tensão} & \textbf{Valor Medido / \newline Multímetro} & \textbf{Valor Medido / \newline Osciloscópio} & \textbf{Valor Medido / \newline Aquisitor de Dados} \\
\hline
1 Volt &
0,995 V &
0,994 V &
0,992 V \newline
0,998 V \newline
0,993 V \newline
0,993 V \newline
0,997 V \newline
Média: 0,994 V
\\
\hline
2 Volts & 
1,969 V &
1,978 V &
1,988 V \newline
1,981 V \newline
1,966 V \newline
1,971 V \newline
1,976 V \newline
Média: 1,976 V
\\
\hline
5 Volts &
5,013 V &
5,001 V &
5,009 V \newline
5,007 V \newline
5,008 V \newline
5,007 V \newline
5,028 V \newline
Média: 5,011 V
\\
\hline
10 Volts &
9,989 V &
9,997 V &
10,030 V \newline
10,023 V \newline
9,994 V \newline
10,004 V \newline
9,997 V \newline
Média: 10,009 V
\\
\hline
12 Volts &
12,013 V &
12,009 V &
12,037 V\newline
12,030 V\newline
12,028 V\newline
12,034 V\newline
12,044 V\newline
Média: 12,034 V
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:medidas_tensao}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier
%%%% END TABELA MEDIDAS DE TENSÃO
\end{document}
```

Example:

[image]

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your code snipped doesn't indicate -- except that table placement option should be `[htb]` -- that is something wrong with it.